# Visual Studio 2017 configure toolbar IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar

I like to configure Visual Studio's toolbar. I can't find where the "play" button is that is combined with what browser will be used (for web stuff).  It's in the "Standard" toolbar, but I'd like to move it to my own toolbar.

Specifically, I'm talking about this:
[image]

The button turns into the *Continue* button when a breakpoint is hit:
[image]

I can find the "play" button easily enough like this:

Hit *Tools* -> *Customize* -> *Commands* -> *Add Commands*

At this point, you have to choose a category, in which case, the *Debug* category is the one that has the green "play" buttons (of which I'd like to find the green play button that includes the **IIS Express (Preferred Browser)** dropdown).

[image]

Alas, if I choose any of the shown buttons, it only puts the green arrow itself on my toolbar, *not* what I'm looking for -- which is the green arrow with the browser dropdown as shown above.

[image]

Does anyone know how to add this button to the Visual Studio ribbon?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to modify the top menu on VS arbitrarily.

Comment: I modify the heck out of it (there's a screenshot in my example above of me modifying it).  It's that one specific button that I can't seem to get.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that's a custom menu built in by default. What I did was export my current settings, then reset my toolbars to default.  The IIS Express button came back.  Then I just did a screenshot and re-added the button and sub-menu manually.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: One thing, after you re-add the "Debug Target" submenu to the Standard toolbar, you have to close the Customize window and re-open it to see and edit the Standard | Debug Target submenu.

Comment: This is the right answer, but man is system for customizing Visual Studio poorly designed.